# Discrete Value Stream Source Probability

Tags: statistics

I am working on a problem that requires me to establish some baseline on a dataset, in which there is an unknown point in time at which the dataset transitions from one source of data to another.  The following toy problem models the situation I am trying to solve:

> Consider a situation involving two people on either end of a one-way
> telegraph line.  The telegraph line can transmit only numbers, and can
> transmit any single number per transmission.  The person on the
> receiving end writes down every number that comes across the
> telegraph.  The person on the other side of the telegraph has a set of
> balls in a bowl, containing every number over some range.  They take
> some (but not all) of the balls out of the bowl and put them in a box.
>
> The person with the numbered balls begins by taking a ball out of the
> bowl, sending the number over the telegraph, and putting the ball back
> in the bowl.  The person on the receiving end writes this number down.
> This process repeats for some amount of time, with the person on the
> sending end drawing numbers from only the bowl.  Then, at some point
> in time, that person decides to switch from the bowl to the box, and
> starts strictly drawing numbers from the box.  The person on the
> receiving end of the telegraph has no knowledge of how many balls
> there are total, nor how many are placed in the box instead of being
> left in the bowl.
>
> The problem is this: from the perspective of the receiving person,
> determine the probability that the most recent number received came
> from the box (instead of the bowl).
>
> For example, you have received the following sequence of numbers: 1,
> 7, 14, 8, 7, 1, 8, 7, 1.  The next number you receive is 3.  What is
> the probability that this number (3) came from the box?

Is there an existing statistical model or well-known equation that works well for this situation?

Comment: @joriki I believe the last sentence of the second paragraph should include those answers - the receiving person does not know either how many balls (numbers) were originally in the bowl, nor how many were moved to the box.  I'm open to answers that make some assumptions about the estimated number of balls present, but ideally a general-case solution would not require any assumptions about either of these values.  In general, it is safe to assume that all possible counts of moved numbers should be equally likely.

Comment: My bad – sorry for missing that. I'll try to make up for it by posting an answer :-) I've deleted my misguided comments – but I think yours is useful to keep nevertheless.